# Inno Script - How to make "I Accept the Agreement" radio button on EULA page selected by Default

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup I have and End-user license agreement page which has "I accept the agreement" and "I don't accept the agreement."

How can I make the "I accept" radio button selected by default?

Comment: That does kinda defeat the point of having the "I agree". It should be an explicit action to agree.

Comment: @Deanna: for some licenses, there's no reason to disagree. Think of CC0 and similar.

Comment: @thomas, then why have the option at all?

Comment: "why have the option at all" - it might be as simple as the application's license requires it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check the `LicenseAcceptedRadio` control from script code:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Checked := True;
end;
```